# Como pegar Serial do Dispositivo no PHONEGAP?

Tags: jquery, android, apache-cordova, get

Preciso Fazer um get utilizando phonegap. Ao Final da URL gostaria de adicionar o ID do dispositivo para consultar se o mesmo já está cadastrado ou não no banco de dados.
Para o envio utilizo a função Ajax do Jquery. Abaixo segue o Código:

```
<script>
     window.onload =  function(){
                document.addEventListener('deviceready', iniciar);
                    function iniciar(){   
                        console.log('App Iniciado');
                        };

                    };

         $(document).ready(function(e){
            var a = device.serial;
              $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "https://localhost/aulaphonegap/consulta.php?s="+a,  
                dataType:'json',
                timeout:5000,
                success: function(e){
                    if(e.Resp == 1){
                           console.log(e.Resp);

                         }else{
                            console.log("Segunda Opção");
                    }

                },
                error: function(e) {
                alert('Aviso!: ' + e.message);
                }
            })

          });
```

Comment: pelo que entendi o seu codigo ja pega o serial você quer fazer a validação no banco correto?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.

Comment: Sua pergunta *"Como pegar Serial do Dispositivo no PHONEGAP?"* já não é respondida com o `var a = device.serial;`?

Comment: Não funcionou dessa forma. Retorna Vazio